# I need help shuffling integers in blackjack, C

Tags: c, struct, shuffle, blackjack

I have three different functions, one too fill the deck, one too shuffle and one too deal cards. I have implemented my `int value` in the function fillDeck and that's working fine. But when I shuffling my value in the same function as deck its not working, I don't get any errors but when I debug visual studio says it's unable to read memory. What am I doing wrong?

fillDeck function

```
void fillDeck(Card * const Deck, const char *suit[], const char *deck[], const int *value[]){

int s;

for (s = 0; s < 52; s++){
    Deck[s].suits = deck[s % 13];
    Deck[s].decks = suit[s / 13];
    Deck[s].value = value[s % 13];
}
return;
}
```

shuffle function

```
void shuffle(Card * const Deck, const int *value[]){
int i, j;
Card temp;

for (i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    j = rand() % 52;
    temp = Deck[i];
    Deck[i] = Deck[j];
    Deck[j] = temp;
    value[i] = value[j]; // <-- this is not working
}
return;
}
```

deal function

```
void deal(const Card * const Deck, int size, int size_1, int size_2){

int i, j, length;
char anotherCard[2];
char name1[30];
char name2[30];

printf("Name player one > ");
scanf("%s", name1);
printf("Name player two > ");
scanf("%s", name2);

printf("\nWelcome %s and %s, lets begin!\n\n", name1, name2);
getchar();

    printf("%s's card:\n", name1);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');
    }
return;
}
```

main function

```
int main(void){

Card allCards[52];
Card cardValue[52];
char *suitname[] = { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs" };
char *deckname[] = { "ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king" };
int cardvalue[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };

srand(time(NULL));

fillDeck(allCards, suitname, deckname, cardvalue);
shuffle(allCards, cardValue);
deal(allCards, 2, 4, 6);


getchar();
return 0;
}
```

func.h file

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

typedef struct card{
    const char *suits;
    const char *decks;
    int value;
};

typedef struct card Card;

void fillDeck(Card * const Deck, char *suit[], char *deck[], const int *value[]);

void shuffle(Card * const Deck, const int *value[]);

void deal(const Card * const Deck, int size, int size_1, int size_2);

#endif
```

Comment: It's hard to suggest anything useful with incomplete code. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's not clear what the `value` array represents in function `shuffle()`, but it's very suspicious that you perform a simple assignment instead of performing the same kind of swapping that you do with `Deck`.

Comment: In your `fillDeck` function you have `Deck[s].suits = deck[s % 13];` and `Deck[s].decks = suit[s / 13];`. Those look a bit mixed up.

Comment: Why does your `shuffle` function need two parameters? You only need to pass it a pointer to (the first element) of your array of cards. I'd also change the shuffle routine to swap `Deck[0]` with `Deck[rand() % 52]`, `Deck[1]` with `Deck[1 + rand() % 51]`, `Deck[2]` with `Deck[2 + rand() % 50]`, etc. You can do that by changing `j = rand() % 52` to `j = i + rand() % (52 - i)` in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `value` is a part of your struct `Card`, it is sufficient to shuffle your array of `Cards` alone. I can't see your full code, but i think there is no need of shuffle any 'valus'. Adapt your function `shuffle` like this.

```
void shuffle( Card * const Deck ){
   for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        int j = rand() % 52;
        Card temp = Deck[i];
        Deck[i] = Deck[j];
        Deck[j] = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

According to this change your function `deal` like this:

```
void deal(const Card * const Deck, int size, int size_1, int size_2) {
    ...
    printf("%s's card:\n", name1);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf to printf("%5s of %-8s %d %d", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, Deck[i].value, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n'); 
                                                                         // ^^^^^^^
    }
    ...
}
```

Apart from  this you have to change the type of the 4th parameter of your function `fillDeck` from `const int *value[]` to `const int value[]`, because `cardvalue` is an array of `int` and not an array of `int*`

```
void fillDeck(Card * const Deck, const char *suit[], const char *deck[], const int value[] );
                                                                               // ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You told the compiler you weren't changing value's ints with:

```
const int *value
```

the you changed one of them with:

```
value[i] = value[j];
```

Also, don't you want to **swap** `value[i]` and `value[j]`?

You have other places where const is misused.

Finally, another way to debug your program is by putting in "printf's of interesting values, etc. in it.  For example:

```
printf("about to swap value[%d]=(%d) and value[%d]=(%d)\n",
    i, j, value[i], value[j]);
value[i] = value[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `shuffle` to something like this:

```
void shuffle(Card * Deck){
    int i, j;
    Card temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        j = i + rand() % (52 - i);
        temp = Deck[i];
        Deck[i] = Deck[j];
        Deck[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
shuffle(allCards);
```

No need to pass the values array - the `Card` type includes the card's value already.